# Showing the uniqueness of the set of distinct naturals $a,b,c>1$ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I was asked whether distinct natural numbers $a,b,c>1$ exist such that
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1$$

I thought of an answer, then wondered if I could prove it was the only answer, and am now asking for assistance on the proof.

Easier: if we altered the question slightly to find $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=1$, if you momentarily disregard the obvious fact that $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}<1$ and all other $b$ yield smaller fractions than $\frac{1}{3}$, you can approach it as:

$$ab=a+b \Rightarrow a(b-1)=b \Rightarrow a=\frac{b}{b-1}$$

Since $a$ is a whole number, $b$ can only be $2$, but that then forces $a$ to be $2$, contrary to our supposition that $a \neq b$. So a solution does not exist.

Returning to the original problem we would have:

$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=1 \Rightarrow abc=ab+bc+ac$$

Plainly, we must add constraints. If we set $c=ab$ this becomes:

$$a^2b^2=ab+b^2a+a^2b \Rightarrow ab=1+a+b \Rightarrow a(b-1)=b+1 \Rightarrow a=\frac{b+1}{b-1}$$

Since $a$ is a natural number, only $b=2,3$ satisfy, leading to a single solution, arising from the constraint that $c=ab$ (which I took from my known solution).

The constraint that would seem to capture all possibilities, and provide my proof, is something like $c=a+k$ with $k$ a natural number $>1$. If I follow that path, I end up with:

$$a^2(b-1)+a(bk-2b-k)-bk=0 \Rightarrow a=\frac{-(bk-2b-k) \pm \sqrt{k^2(b-1)^2+4b^2}}{2(b-1)}$$

The formula checks out - the radical yields 3 Pythagorean triples for my known possible values of $b,k$, but from a forward-looking view of the problem, I can't see how to dig the terms out of the radical to establish the only valid solutions.

The missing piece is to show that this expression under the radical is a perfect square: $$k^2(b-1)^2+(2b)^2=k^2b^2-2k^2b+k^2+4b^2$$

If you see how to re-express that as a square, please tell me.

I would be interested to hear other approaches to the proof. Also, I know this is the only solution from https://oeis.org/A006585, I'm interested in the how/why, not the fact that the solution is unique.

Edit: drew out the expression that needs re-expressing at the end.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work.  Simpler: order them as $a>b>c$.  Then $c=2$ since otherwise the sum would be too small. Now we have $\frac 1a+\frac 1b=\frac 12$, so argue that $b=3$ and so on.

Comment: Yes that is like the approach I illustrated for the 2-fraction case. It is fast and simple, but also doesn't reveal much about the structure of the solution. Which is why I approached it from a more Diophantine point of view.

Comment: "Since  is a natural number, there is only one value for  that satisfies" is wrong. You can have $b=2$ or $b=3$

Comment: Oops - thanks - gonna fix that part - they lead to the same solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution (but not to the original expression):

Begin with $abc=ab+bc+ac$

Set $a<b<c$ and $b=a+j$ and $c=a+k$

Then substitute, arriving at:

$a^2-jk=(a-2)(a+j)(a+k)$

If $a=2$ then $a^2=jk$ forcing $a=2; b=3; c=6$

Else if $a \neq 2$ then divide out $(a-2)$:

$a+2 + \frac{4-jk}{a-2}=(a+j)(a+k)$

Since $a,j,k$ are positive integers and $a \neq2$, $\frac{4-jk}{a-2}$ is a negative integer, yet:

$0>\frac{4-jk}{a-2} = a^2+a(j+k)+jk-a-2=a^2+a(j+k-1)+(jk-2)>0$

So $0>0$ which is absurd so $a \neq 2$ is impossible.